# How to enable workflow state 'write' on selected item?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

Some items don't have write access right due to workflow state write not being granted.
When I click write access right in Access Viewer

[image]

Access Viewer informs me that selected user don't have access right due to workflowstate write acess right:

[image]

Unfortunately I'm not able to set it 'manualy' through security editor:

[image]

Can anyone shed some light on this ?
Thanks

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I've had to come back to this question and answer. Thanks!

Comment: Cause it's definitely more than twice. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Browse to the item which represents this workflow state. According to your sample, it should be /sitecore/system/workflow/MediaPublishing/StartAndPublish. Make sure write access is allowed for that user to this workflow state item.

Comment: Just to re-iterate make sure "Workflow State Write" access is given not the generic Write access.