# Sitecore Role Access Settings Not Working

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I've created a role in Sitecore, and I'm configuring the item access in the Access Viewer.  However, after I assign the security settings to allow "read", "write" and "create" permissions, only the "read" and "create" rights are highlighted in "green."  The "write" permission is still "red".  Since this is a brand new role that I just created, what could be causing this to occur?

[image: Security Settings Assigned As This]

[image: Actual Permissions - after settings have been assigned]

Comment: In the Access Viewer, click on the individual permission (e.g. Write) and in the right hand side it will show you how it calculates that permission. It sounds like you are inheriting from a role which explicitly denies Write access. You should break inheritance instead

Comment: Figured this out, through a related post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045960/how-to-enable-workflow-state-write-on-selected-item  This is done at the item-level, where you can configure the workflow state item access for a specific role.  I had never done this before, but it made sense after I saw where you do this.